# Use millions of CALayers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, nsview

I am trying to use multiple thousand `CALayers` in a `NSView`. Is there an efficient way to draw let's say a million `CALayers` without any performance issues? For now, whenever I draw 100000 `CALayers`, the window can't handle it and lags during resize.
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847671/calayer-optimizations) article about `CALayer` optimization but  found no answer.
Has someone some experience or ideas in doing this?

Comment: The short answer is no. You're asking too much. Look into [CALayer shouldRasterize]. It might help you out some.

Comment: Why could you possibly need that many CALayers?

Comment: If you have a 15 inch MacBook Pro with Retina display, you have about 5 million pixels on the display. Note that those are pixels and not points. You still only have about 1.3 million _points_ on the screen (4 pixels per point). Having one million layers would mean that they are about 1 point in size each. Having 5 million layers would mean that they are about 1 pixel (quarter of a point) on a 15 inch retina MacBook Pro. *Why would you need millions of layers?*

Comment: @danielbeard Well, I just trying to find a way to get a big amount of event handling (like hovering or dragging) areas in a view. They could very well overlap. It could be a quarter million, the point is, that after 100000 layers, the view can't handle it without lagging.

Comment: Not sure what a "big amount of event handling" means… but if you want the absolute limit of hovering (mouse over?) or dragging just use the NSEvent mouseMoved or mouseDragged methods and perform hit testing on what ever objects the mouse might be over/dragging at that time.

Comment: I have quite some experience in [drawing lots of files and folders](http://www.raskinformac.com) with `CALayer`. Make sure your layers don't contain too big image contents. Use `OpenGL Profiler` to see what textures are loaded. Also `CATextLayer`s have to be treated carefully. And @DavidRönnqvist is right, what can the user actually see at this moment?